# Jenkins how to poll scm without kicking off a job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-job-dsl

This is the first time using Jenkins DSL pull jobs. All my jobs are loaded via CasC. I thought and want to have a setup where scm is polled every 15mins to keep jobs up to date from GitLab repo. Most of my dozen jobs are to be triggered manually and about three that are scheduled to run lets say everyday at 10am.

But what I am experiencing is every time I submit to the develop branch, ALL the jobs get sunk and executed.

In my CasC Jenkins file:

```
jobs:
  - script: >
      folder('App/scheduled')
  - file: /var/jenkins_home/pipelines/pull_app_server_deploy_m23_dev_devops_daily
```

The pull job **pull_app_server_deploy_m23_dev_devops_daily**:

```
pipelineJob("App/scheduled/M23 dev_devops daily deploy") {
  disabled(false)
  definition {
    cpsScm {
      scm {
        git {
          remote {
            url("https://gitlab.domain.com/Common/tools/jenkins.git")
            credentials("*******************************")
          }
          branch('develop')
        }
      }
      scriptPath("jobs/app_server_deploy_m23_dev_devops_daily")
    }
  }
  triggers {
    scm('H/15 * * * *')
  }
}
```

Then in my actual pipeline job I have something like this:

```
env.agentName = ""

pipeline {
    agent any

    triggers {
        cron('0 15 * * 1-5')
    }

    stages {

        stage ('Decide which agent') {
            steps {
                script {
                    env.agentName = "co-dev-deploy01"
                    echo "Will execute on ${env.agentName}"
                }
            }
        }

        stage ('App Deploy') {
            options {
                timeout(time: 3600, unit: 'SECONDS')
            }

            steps {
                node ( agentName as String ) {
                    dir("/opt/home/p4/tools/ansible/ML/2023/deploy_conf") {
                        ansiblePlaybook([
                            credentialsId: 'co-ssh',
                            inventory: "inventory/dev_devops",
                            playbook: 'deploy_app_server.yml',
                            vaultCredentialsId: "vault_dev_devops_passwd",
                            colorized   : true,
                            extraVars   : [
                                deploy_env: "dev_devops",
                                cl_to_deploy: "latest",
                                build_type: "debug-opt",
                                deploy_cluster: "all",
                                restart_wait_time: "1",
                                restart_mysql_schema_clear: "None",
                                individual_schemas: "",
                                mysql_soft_fail_enable: false,
                                redis_restart: true,
                                redis_hard_stop: true,
                                clean_build: false,
                                branch: "DL"
                            ]
                        ])
                    }
                }

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Am I missing something? Is there another parameter I am missing to tell it not to execute after syncing? In the GUI, when looking at the job configuration I do see that the above code translates to:

Build Triggers:

```
build periodically (0 15 * * 1-5) <-- which is what is desired.
Poll SCM (H/15 * * * *)           <-- which I want the polling but not to trigger.
```

I only have two branches setup which are **develop** and **main**, nothing else. Maybe I need to restructure my repo?

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to remove this:

```
  triggers {
    scm('H/15 * * * *')
  }
```

It's redundant and causes the file to execute. I made an assumption that that piece above would control the scm polling, but that is separate. So remove that piece, as the pull job will poll on its own.